# Getting error when i start Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

It was working fine, suddenly i am getting below error after resetting user data using this `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`command.

[image: An Error Occurred]

Comment: try using `devenv.exe/setup` to rebuild the cache.

Comment: @active92 Once i use above command and open visual studio. After couple seconds it disappear and nothing happend.  see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSZFn.png

Comment: i've been trying to search some solutions for you and found `http://blog.simontimms.com/2015/02/12/visual-studio-2015-not-launching/`. hopefully this works. if it doesn't, then you need to reinstall visual studio.

Comment: @active92 It's still not working. I removed that 14.0 folder and using `/resetuserdata` command. still not luck.

Comment: so your situation is that there is no error but visual studio 2015 won't startup?

Comment: @active92 yes, It was working fine but suddenly it's started giving me error on every time i start up visual studio 2015. Based on above errors look like i am getting some kind of setting file error. I have also reset using command line `/resetsettings`.

Comment: can it work in safe mode?

Comment: @active92 yes, i can see it's working but all 3rd party plugin are not.

Comment: @active92 In safe mode Import Export Setting Wizard getting Error         1:  Projects and Solutions: Unable to import property 'ProjectItemTemplatesLocation' because it contains invalid data '%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Templates\ItemTemplates'.
Error 2:  Projects and Solutions: Unable to import property 'ProjectTemplatesLocation' because it contains invalid data '%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Templates\ProjectTemplates'.
Error 3:  Projects and Solutions: Unable to import property 'ProjectsLocation' because it contains invalid data '%vsspv_visualstudio_dir%\Projects'.

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong with your visual studio unless I can reproduce and try to solve it. I would strongly suggest you to reinstall.

Comment: @active92 that's what i am planning to do. Thanks a lot.